# ASP MVC Redirect using Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble with my redirects picking up the existing url. I have a page that has google charts on it where I have added a listener to the bars in a bar chart. When a user clicks on one of the bar charts a case statement determines what id to pass to the router.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper, 'select', selectHandler);

function selectHandler() {
  var selection = wrapper.getChart().getSelection()
     var monthsTransform = 0;
        switch(selection[0].column)
           {
            case 1:
                monthsTransform = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                monthsTransform = 3;
                break;
            case 3:
                monthsTransform = 6;
                break;
            case 4:
                monthsTransform = 12;
                break;
            case 5:
                monthsTransform = 18;
                break;

            //no need to default as already set to 0!
            }
            var url = "newController/newPage/" + monthsTransform;
            window.location.href = url;
        }
```

The problem I have is that the

```
window.location.href
```

is appending the newController/newPage to the existing url, so it ends up like:

```
localhost:1234/oldController/oldPage/newController/newPage/id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window.location.assign("/newController/newPage/" + monthsTransform), instead of window.location.href

It would even be nicer if you added the server name and protocol in front of the new URL, and used Html.Action html helper to generate the url.

Answer (score 0):

Check my blog post on creating URL's on the server side:

http://ilovedevelopment.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/aspnet-mvc-3-generating-actionlink-in.html

The crux of it I've pasted below for brevity - modify as required:

```
string absoluteAction = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",
                                                  Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme,
                                                  Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority,
                                                  Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new {Id = "Data"}));
```

This can be done inside a controller method so you could make an ajax call and return the proper url "absoluteAction" as a Json result.